# Make div selected instead of text in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have highlighted code, each line in div block. When I select text, I need to change background color of all div elements, that contain that selected text.

Now it looks like this (usual text selection):
[image: how select looks now]

I need select lines (div blocks) instead of text, so the result should be like this:[image: how should be]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Code</title>
      <link href='http://agorbatchev.typepad.com/pub/sh/3_0_83/styles/shCore.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <link href='http://agorbatchev.typepad.com/pub/sh/3_0_83/styles/shThemeDefault.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <script src='http://agorbatchev.typepad.com/pub/sh/3_0_83/scripts/shCore.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='http://agorbatchev.typepad.com/pub/sh/3_0_83/scripts/shBrushJava.js' type='text/javascript'></script>   
      <style>
   .syntaxhighlighter .code .container .line:hover {
    background-color: chartreuse !important; 
   }
      </style>   
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="code-snippet">
        <pre class="brush: java">
   package file;

   import com.epam.codereview.manager.servlet.Controller;
   import com.epam.codereview.manager.servlet.RequestMapping;
   import com.epam.codereview.manager.servlet.View;
   import com.epam.codereview.util.FileUtil;
   import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import java.io.IOException;

   /** ffdfdf
    * fdfdfd
    */

   @Controller
   public class MainController {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public void index(View view) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

   }
  </pre>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.defaults['toolbar'] = false;
    SyntaxHighlighter.highlight(); 
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

It should look like hover, but while select text.

Comment: Please post actual code...not images of code. How is anyone supposed to help with code fix suggestions if they can't copy what you are using?

Comment: @Taplar Because after long searching I found nothing in css, pseudo class ::selected didn't help me, so maybe I find solution in js ...

Comment: @Taplar Yes, it's syntaxhighlighter js prettify code.

Comment: Ok, it looks like you updated your question, but without that information it was very obscure as to what you were asking.  You should provide as much information relative to the question as possible.

Comment: @Taplar You're right, I added basic code, with hover effect on div with code line, I need such effect while selecting several lines - to highlight div, not text

Comment: @charlietfl I added code example, maybe it will help to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.getSelection().anchorNode` returns the DOM node in which the user selection begins, and its `.focusNode` returns the node where the selection ends; highlight everything from A to B (bearing in mind that the focusNode may be before the anchorNode...)

Or you can be lazy and just test Selection.containsNode() on every line, as I did here:

```js
$(window).on('mousedown mouseup mousemove', function() {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  if (sel.isCollapsed) {
    // nothing is selected, remove any existing highlights
    $('.line').removeClass('highlight');
  } else {
    $('.line').each(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('highlight', sel.containsNode(this, true));
      // the second param of containsNode causes partially-selected nodes to be included
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #2C86FF;
  color: #FFF;
}
::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background-color: transparent
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1</div>
<div class="line">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2</div>
<div class="line">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3</div>
<div class="line">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 4</div>
<div class="line">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 5</div>
<div class="line">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 6</div>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

(Internet Explorer prior to version 9 doesn't support this, of course; it has the much less useful document.selection).  Personally I'd treat this as a good opportunity to use the phrase "degrades gracefully" :)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not very tidy code, but it works.

Edit: Add the css code to disable selection color.

```
/* Mozilla based browsers */
::-moz-selection {
   background-color: transparent;
}

::selection {
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

```js
var selecting = false, startIndex = null, endIndex = null;

var paint = function(e){
  //e.stopPropagation();
  if(!selecting) return;

  var selection = (document.selection) ? document.selection.createRange().text : document.getSelection();

  if(selection.baseOffset != selection.extentOffset){
      newStartIndex = parseInt(selection.baseNode.parentNode.getAttribute("index"));
      newEndIndex = parseInt(selection.extentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("index"));
      
      if(startIndex != newStartIndex || endIndex != newEndIndex){
          if(startIndex === null) startIndex = newStartIndex;
          if(endIndex === null) endIndex = newEndIndex;
        
          var s = Math.min(startIndex, newStartIndex, newStartIndex, endIndex, newEndIndex);
          var l = Math.max(startIndex, newStartIndex, endIndex, newEndIndex);
          for(var i=s; i<=l; i++){
            var bg = i>Math.max(newEndIndex,newStartIndex) || i<Math.min(newStartIndex,newEndIndex) ? "inherit" : "#ddd";
            $('#div' + i).css("background-color", bg);
          }
        
          startIndex = Math.min(newStartIndex, newEndIndex);
          endIndex = Math.max(newStartIndex, newEndIndex);
      }
  }
};
$('.mydiv').bind('mousemove', paint);
$('.mydiv').bind('mouseover', paint);
$('.mydiv').bind('mousedown', function(){
    console.log('down');
    selecting = true;
});
$('.mydiv').bind('mouseup', function(){
    selecting = false;
    startIndex = null;
    endIndex = null;
});
$(document).mousedown(function(){
    $('.mydiv').css('background-color', 'inherit');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" index="1" class="mydiv">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1</div>
<div id="div2" index="2" class="mydiv">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2</div>
<div id="div3" index="3" class="mydiv">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3</div>
<div id="div4" index="4" class="mydiv">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 4</div>
<div id="div5" index="5" class="mydiv">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 5</div>
<div id="div6" index="6" class="mydiv">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 6</div>
```

Comment: Wow, quick answer! I see you had a similar problem. Thank you!

Comment: No, it just took my attention :) You're welcome.